# Are finite almost simple groups 2-generated?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

This is inspired by

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/59213/generating-finite-simple-groups-with-2-elements

and

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/254164/is-every-finite-quasi-simple-group-generated-by-2-elements

Which show that every finite quasi-simple group is 2-generated (indeed even every finite perfect group which is 2-generated modulo its center is 2-generated)

Is every finite almost simple group https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_simple_group 2-generated?

I think this should roughly reduce to whether the outer automorphism groups of finite simple groups are 2-generated. Outer automorphisms of sporadic groups are cyclic 2 or trivial. Outer automorphism groups of $ A_n $ are mostly cyclic 2, exception $ Aut(A_6)=C_2 \times C_2 $ is still 2-generated.  I think outer automorphisms of finite groups of Lie type are all 2-generated but I have to check.

a lot of small example, for example all the groups here https://brauer.maths.qmul.ac.uk/Atlas/v3/lin/ have 2-generated Out(G)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The minimum number of generators of finite almost simple groups is studied in

*Dalla Volta, Francesca; Lucchini, Andrea*, [**Generation of almost simple groups**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1006/jabr.1995.1345), J. Algebra 178, No. 1, 194-223 (1995). [ZBL0839.20021](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0839.20021).

In the introduction they remark that there are finite simple groups $S$ for which $\operatorname{Aut}(S)$ has $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ as a quotient, and so $\operatorname{Aut}(S)$ is not $2$-generated.

For example, this is the case for $S=PSL(4,9)$.

Comment: In fact they prove that, for all finite nonabelian simple groups $S$, the minimal number of generators of ${\rm Aut}(S)$ is the same as that of ${\rm Aut}(S)/S$, and this is at most $3$.